# Avro DataFileWriter API metadata

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I have preparing AVRO data with deflateCodec compression, when i am preparing data with 10 batch, each time when i prepare it is adding schema definition in to the file, is it possible to avoid adding schema definition.

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://github.com/hailpam/avro-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/org/pm/avro/test/AvroSerializer.java

Comment: Thank for the reply, i'm using dataFileWriter.